# C++ std::bind() Parameter of Memberfunction

Tags: c++, std, function-pointers

I want to use `std::function` of a member function and provide it via return value. What is the syntax `std::bind(...)` for that?

```cpp
class Test{
    int move(int x){
        return x * Y;
    }
    std::function<int(int)> getFunc(){
        std::function<int(int)> tmp2 = std::bind(&Test::move, _1, this);
        return tmp2;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `std::bind(&Test::move, this, _1);`.

Lambda is an alternative:

```
std::function<int(int)> tmp2 = [this](int i) { return move(i); };
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should change the position of `this` and `_1` when passing to `std::bind`. Secondly, `Test::move` should return `int`.

```
class Test{
    int move(int x){
       return ...; 
    }

    std::function<int(int)> getFunc(){
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        std::function<int(int)> tmp2 = std::bind(&Test::move, this, _1);
        return tmp2;
    }
};
```